# PyQt5 grid layout expands for big widgets, but doesn't contract for small widgets

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt5, pyqt5

**Question:** How can I make a PyQt grid layout shrink when the size of a widget decreases?

## Desired Behavior

Display a long string in a label in a PyQt grid layout. The grid expands to accomodate the label. When the label is reset to a shorter string, the grid, no longer needing the extra space, contracts.

## Actual Behavior

The grid expands to accomodate a long label, but doesn't contract when the 
label becomes shorter. It remains at its expanded size.

#### Initial State

[image: Initial state]

#### Displaying the long label

[image: Displaying the long label]

#### Grid stays expanded after label is cleared

[image: Grid stays expanded after the label is cleared]

## Minimal example using PyQt5 (5.7) in Python 3.5

The example below includes two buttons and a label. One button sets the label to 400 character long string of asterisks. The other sets the label to the empty string.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)


class TestUI(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lbl_feedback = QLabel('Long string goes here', self)

        btn_long_string = QPushButton('Display a long string', self)
        btn_long_string.clicked.connect(self._show_feedback_label)

        btn_clear = QPushButton('Clear the long string', self)
        btn_clear.clicked.connect(self._hide_feedback_label)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(5)

        # assemble grid
        grid.addWidget(self.lbl_feedback, 0, 1, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(btn_long_string, 1, 1, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(btn_clear, 2, 1, Qt.AlignCenter)

        # resize weights
        grid.setColumnStretch(0, 10)
        grid.setColumnStretch(1, 10)
        grid.setColumnStretch(2, 10)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

    def _show_feedback_label(self):
        long_string = '*' * 400
        self.lbl_feedback.setText(long_string)

    def _hide_feedback_label(self):
        self.lbl_feedback.setText('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test_ui = TestUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is impossible for main window because i can't find it in Qt Designer. But you can call mainwindow.adjustSize() on label.changed signal.

Update:
Sorry, I was wrong. QLabel has no "changed" signal.
Other way:

```
def _hide_feedback_label(self):
    self.lbl_feedback.setText('')

    self.adjustSize() # <--
```